# WCF Authentication / WCF REST Authetication..Different Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, rest

I have made a WCF REST service which consumes data from an OLAP database and it is not Microsoft technology, ultimately, I would like to connect many other OLAP database to a single platform.

And after a lot of reading, the security for WCF REST is very discouraging, in summary, I have 2 choices, one is to use the Basic Authentication which expose username and password over the wire, or maybe a bit better, using Basic Authentication with SSL, now I need to get different certificates from the webserver. Or using Digest Authentication, which use an encrypted password and authenticate against the database, that's the best option, but in my case, it is not possible as I am not using Microsoft technology, the security is on different platform and I cannot encrypt my password using MD5 because the database cannot read the encrypted password.

That concludes me only be able to use Basic Authentication with SSL, but is this the correct way of doing? I see many products out there doing something similar to what I do, when they login, I do not see https, but only http, are they not secure and easy to hack?

I am not trying to make a bullet proof website, but a simple website, using Basic Authentication is too simple, or in fact it's almost like giving away the password, but using https, is that overkill?

So, after REST being that discouraging, let's not use REST, use the normal WCF, from what I have read, they shares the same problem.

Please give me some guidance. I think I have lost.

Many Thanks

PlayKid

Answer (score 1):

Often, basic authentication is used for regular websites and yes, the username and password often go over the line readable if used with http. Https is already better, because the information is send encrypted over the line. But in practice, you only see this in place for commercial or banking applications. You cannot use MD5, which is a pitty, because that would be sort of middle-of-the-road approach.

So, depending on the application you will expose, use http for simplicity or https with a bit more complexity and safety.

By the way, big safety problems often have to do with SQL injection or a hacker being able to get some admin level privileges on your site. That way they get acess to a lot of info, while sniffing your line and getting a single user password combination is *relatively* harmless, if you take the needed precautions and counter measures.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Basic authentication with SSL is really very secure and shoul be used if its going to be exposed to outside world.

One easiest hack approach I have seen before and if you just want to authenticate (not authorize a endpoint) clients which are known set of clients use:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

This will provide username accessing the service, Authenticate this usern with your DB or AD using LDAP if a valid user is accessing the service and with every request add a encrypted key that user needs to send as part of request. This way you know the username and encrypted key from the request.

You can also use this along with Basic authentication to be sure its not insecure.